# Joomla transfer URL parameters from article to IFRAME in Wrapper module

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, joomla

I have a simple PHP script, that receives some parameters through the URL

> www.mydomain.com/myscript.php?user_id=John

This script will display some info about John.

I want to put this script in a Joomla Article, and I managed to do that through the use of the Wrapper Module (iframe), but I'm quite unsure how to pass the parameter to it.

My articles URL will be something like www.mydomain.com/myarticle, and I'm curious whether it's possible to pass a parameter to this URL, that would be forwarded to the php script in the iframe...?

Comment: never used the Wrapper module, can you show how the iframe url is declared in the module? we could also like to know how is stored the user id, to know from what to retreive it

Comment: Well, this is also my question, to know how it should be declared. The user_id as a parameter was just an example. don't mix it up with the joomla user_id, that can be requested via the Joomla PHP API.

Comment: i looked a little at this module, it seems that being an fixed URL stored in a field, you will probably have a little trouble passing the parameter by URL. Quick workarounds would be to try stuff like php session variables through the Joomla function `$app->setUserState`, or even cookies. But if you want a clean solution to do that, you should better put your script inside a custom module or plugin, they are quite easy to create, and the best place to use php.. (solutions like creating a shortcode for php code in articles is also possible, but more dirty)